# How can I make node or edge label CREATE in AgensGraph?

Tags: graph-databases, reserved-words, agens-graph

I have been making a text analysis system with AgensGraph.

And I use the SPO model of RDF triple structure as graph-schema.
But I faced one problem: AgensGraph doesn't allow CREATE labels.

I think CREATE is one of reserved word in AgensGraph.
Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: I slightly reworded/formatted your question to make it more readable. Please review my changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AgensGraph is one of Graph database Based on Postgres.

So many query language grammar of AgensGraph are almost identical to Postgres.

You can see a nice table of reserved words in PostgreSQL:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

An alternative, however, is to enclose the identifier in double-quotes.